# PHP - make query to JSON file with AND condition

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

I’m trying to query some data from a JSON file with PHP, i want to get objects based on `string` and `number`.

Here’s my JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": "5V28tqJ1",
        "string": "john doe",
        "number": 1,
        "aArray": [
            "cc",
            "kk",
            "lo",
            "mm"
        ],
        "bool": false,
        "createdAt": "2020-01-02T15:16:11",
        "updatedAt": "2020-01-05T19:37:02"
    },
    {
        "id": "PMuKM818",
        "string": "sarah doe",
        "number": 2,
        "aArray": [
            "bb",
            "cc"
        ],
        "bool": true,
        "createdAt": "2020-01-02T16:16:23",
        "updatedAt": "2020-01-05T19:37:14"
    },
    {
        "id": "m8HSbEQe",
        "string": "bob smith",
        "number": 3,
        "aArray": [
            "dd",
            "ee",
            "ff"
        ],
        "bool": false,
        "createdAt": "2020-01-02T17:16:36",
        "updatedAt": "2020-01-05T19:37:32"
    }
]
```

Here’s my `query-user.php` script:

```
<?php include 'header.php';
$string = $_GET['string'];
$aArray = $_GET['aArray'];
$number = $_GET['number'];
$bool = $_GET['bool'];

$data = file_get_contents($className. '.json');
$data = json_decode($data);

$results = array();

for ($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++) {

    // check value in string
    if(isset($string)){
        if (strpos($data[$i]->string, $string) !== false) {
            array_push($results, $data[$i]);
        }
    }

    // check element in array
    if(isset($aArray)){
        if (in_array($aArray, $data[$i]->aArray)) {
            array_push($results, $data[$i]);
        } 
    }

    // check value in number
    if(isset($number)){
        if (strpos($data[$i]->number, $number) !== false) {
            array_push($results, $data[$i]);
        } 
    }

    // check value in bool
    if(isset($bool)){
        if ($data[$i]->bool == $bool) {
            array_push($results, $data[$i]);
        }
    }

}// ./ for

echo json_encode($results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

On my browser, I call the following url:

```
http://example.com/users/query-user.php?string=doe&number=2
```

Here’s what I get as result:

```
[ 
{ "id": "5V28tqJ1", "string": "john doe", "number": 1, "aArray": [ "cc", "kk", "lo", "mm" ], "bool": false, "createdAt": "2020-01-02T15:16:11", "updatedAt": "2020-01-05T19:37:02" }, 
{ "id": "PMuKM818", "string": "sarah doe", "number": 2, "aArray": [ "bb", "cc" ], "bool": true, "createdAt": "2020-01-02T16:16:23", "updatedAt": "2020-01-05T19:37:14" },
{ "id": "PMuKM818", "string": "sarah doe", "number": 2, "aArray": [ "bb", "cc" ], "bool": true, "createdAt": "2020-01-02T16:16:23", "updatedAt": "2020-01-05T19:37:14" }
 ]
```

As you can see, I get the object with ID `PMuKM818` twice, while I should get it once, together with the first object.

What am I doing wrong in my php code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object with the ID `PMuKM818` corresponds to both of your query parameters: it contains Doe and also has the number 2.

If you want to prevent that, either set an order of precedence for your filters using `if else` statements instead of simple `if`, or add a check for existing ids in the resulting array before adding the element.

**ADDITIONAL EDIT**

Not the most elegant solution but it does what you need:

```
foreach ($data as $details) {

    // check value in string
    if(isset($string)){
        if (strpos($details->string, $string) !== false) {
            $results[$details->id] = $details;
        }
    }

    // check element in array
    if(isset($aArray)){
        if (in_array($aArray, $details->aArray)) {
            $results[$details->id] = $details;
        } 
    }

    // check value in number
    if(isset($number)){
        if (strpos($details->number, $number) !== false) {
            $results[$details->id] = $details;
        } 
    }

    // check value in bool
    if(isset($bool)){
        if ($details->bool == $bool) {
            $results[$details->id] = $details;
        }
    }

}// ./ for

echo json_encode(array_values($results), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

I've also replaced the `for` loop with a `foreach`, but that should not impact on the result

Comment: I’ve tried using else if, but it was wrong. May you edit your question with sone sample code? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code, anyway if i use “ http://example.com/users/query-user.php?number=3&string=john”, i get only the first object, not the third one too.. That’s why i’ve said that i’ve already tried the else if statements, as you did, but the result is not what i need

Comment: Thanks, now it does what i need!

Answer (score 1):

For quick answer you just need to use: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column

What is fastest way to process json objects.

UPDATE:

for full your code correct please use: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search

combinate with array_column, what way you will search more faster then one by one.

Comment: Thanks, may you post a sample code related to my question? That will help me a lot, i’m a newbie :)